# Error with Pandas program to get the items of a given series not present in another given series

Tags: python, pandas, series

Basically a program to get the items of a the first series not present in second series.
First Series = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Second Series = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

Expected Ans: [1,3,5]

**My Code**

```
import pandas as pd

sr1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
sr2 = pd.Series([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])

l = []

for i in sr1:
  if(i not in sr2):
    l.append(i)

print(l)
```

**My Output**

```
[5]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[1,3,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pandas method isin:

```
sr1[~sr1.isin(sr2)]
```

This will print the elements from sr1 that do not (~) appear in sr2.